# Displaying an arrays index number

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing, minimum-spanning-tree

I need help with C#

I'm currently trying to find the minimum value in a 2D array. I have managed to do this however, after I have found the minimum value I want the corresponding values index number (Where it is stored in my 2D array) to be output. For example, I have a 2D and a 1D array. Once the minimum value has been discovered the index value for the 2D array needs to be changed in the 1D array.

The 2d array is c[i,j] 
and the 1D array is a[i]

so how would i be able to display the j number in my c array in my a array. For example, if my minimum value was at c[1,5] I want the value in a[5] to be changed from 0 to 1. Any help would be great thanks!

P.S. if ive made this sound really confusing I apologise I'm new to this !

```
   int n = 5, m = 10, MinValue = 100, MaxValue = 1, Total = 0, Sum = 0; //n = number of values    m = max value in array MinValue = Lowest number in array
        Random Rand = new Random();

        int[] A = new int[n + 1];

        for (int i = 1; i < n+1; i++)   //Reached and unreached array - creation
        {
            A[i] = 0;
        }
        A[1] = 1;

        int[,] c = new int[n + 1, n + 1];   //Create array


        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            {
                c[i, j] = Rand.Next(1, m);      //Randomise the array
                if (i == j)
                {
                    c[i, j] = 99;               // give void spaces the value of 99
                }
                if (c[i, j] > MaxValue && c[i, j] < 99)
                {
                    MaxValue = c[i, j];     // max value takes the highest value (that isnt 99)
                }




            }

        }

        for (int p = 1; p <= n; p++)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= n+1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; i <= n+1; i++)
                {
                    if (c[i, j] <= MinValue)
                    {
                        if (A[i] == 1)
                        {
                            if (A[i] == 0)
                            {
                                Total = Sum + MinValue;
                                Sum = Total;
                                A[i] = 1;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Total Value = " + Total);
        Console.WriteLine("");


        Console.WriteLine("The tracking array - what has been reached and what hasn't"); // Output reaching array
        Console.WriteLine("");
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
                Console.WriteLine("A[" + i +  "] = " + A[i].ToString("00") + " ");

            //Output the array to screen
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("The link length array"); // Output link length array
        Console.WriteLine("");

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("c[" + i + "," + j + "] = " + c[i, j].ToString("00") + " ");

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            //Output the array to screen
        }

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Post your code, and we'll go from there.

Comment: What have you tried, why isn't it working, what line did your debugging tell you its failing, what research did you do. Stack overflow isn't a help me site, its a site for enthusiast and professional programmers that can draw value from previous questions and answers, and as it turns out this (at the moment) is of very little value to you or anyone else

Comment: Do you mean that if C[i,j] has minimum value then , we have to put A[j]  = i ?

Comment: I've added my code and im not too sure whats not working. it's meant to be creating a minimum spanning tree code in which my second array becomes full of 1's at the end which means all nodes have been reached and it also outputs the total for all of the links added together.

Comment: in the C array [i] is already reached meaning it is a 1 in the A array. so that means when the minimum value is chosen the J value should then be changed from a 0 to 1 in the A arrray. Im just not sure how to get the A one to change depending on the C array. Hope that helps.

Comment: Also a good thing to note is that in c# arrays are zero-based, meaning the index of the first element is 0. So instead of creating arrays storing 5 elements you're creating arrays that contain 6 elements and completely ignoring the element at index 0. So apart from any answer to your question I advise you to rewrite your array code to create arrays of size n (new int[n]) and loop from 0 to n (for (var i = 0; i< n; i++)).